# deduced return type depedent on member function template argument

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to figure out what's wrong with this code:

```
#include <string>

struct Bar
{
    using Deduced = typename std::string;
};

class Test
{
    template<typename Foo>
    auto Func() ->  decltype(Foo::Deduced)
    {
        return Foo::Deduced();
    }
};

int main()
{
    Test t;
    std::string ret = t.template Func<Bar>();
}
```

I am refactoring a class where `Func` return type was declared as a template class parameter of `Test` class, but I would like to change this to work as a member template parameter.

Is this possible?
If yes, anyone could suggest me the right syntax?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the `decltype`.

`decltype` gives the type of an *expression*. But `Foo::Deduced` is already a type, so you can't apply `decltype` to it. You simply want to refer to that type itself. So all you have to do is write `Foo::Deduced`.

However, in some contexts, you need to prefix it with `typename` to tell the compiler that it's really a type. In C++20, you need `typename` in `return Foo::Deduced()` but you don't need it in the trailing return type. Prior to C++20, it was needed in both places. Thus your code could be rewritten like so:

```
template<typename Foo>
auto Func() ->  Foo::Deduced
{
    return typename Foo::Deduced();
}
```

Or a deduced return type could be used:

```
template<typename Foo>
decltype(auto) Func()  // notice no trailing return type
{
    return typename Foo::Deduced();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In this alias declaration

```
using Deduced = typename std::string;
```

the keyword `typename` is redundant. Just write

```
using Deduced = std::string;
```

The template function `Func` is a private member function of the class `Test`. You need to make it public.

The `decltype` specifier expects an expression. You should write at least like

```
auto Func() ->  typename Foo::Deduced
```